# Is service is started automatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am new to android .Is service in android is started automatically when the mobile is switch on??if yes that's great.if no can any one explain how can i start the particular service ??

Comment: You should read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, service is not started automatically after device boot. but you can register an android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED for Starting Service when Device boot complete as:

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
   </uses-permission>
    <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
        <intent-filter> 
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

---

**BootReceiver.java :**

```
public class BootReceiver extends IntentReceiver 
{

    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    public void onReceiveIntent(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) 
        {
           context.startService(new Intent(context,YourService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In user based application service does not start automatically

you need to add below code

```
<receiver android:name="com.wallpaper.StartReceiver" xmlns:android="#unknown">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

you better read something on Broadcast receiver from here
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

A broadcast receiver is an Android component which allows to register for system or application events(in your case the  ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)

As soon as the Android loads up it broadcast a message that the boot is completed and all the applications that are registered to receivce that event will receive it and you can do your stuff...

It can be done using this code below by adding it to the manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="some_pagacakge_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

here are some links for it 
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-broadcastreceiver/

Answer (score 0):

you can start your service `startService(intent)`

To run it on Phone restart

add following permission in manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

and declared a `Broadcast Receiver` like

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:label="BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and then

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

@Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    try{
        context.startService(new Intent(context,yourServiceName.class));
        Log.i(TAG,"Starting Service yourServiceName");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your requirement what kind of service you want to start and when you want to start that service. if you want to start particular service on startup then you have to register the reciever as Devangi Desai has mentioned and then you need to issue the `startService()` method.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
                context.startService(new Intent(context,
                        ConnectionService.class));
        }
    }
```

Here `ConnectionService.class` is class which extends a service and has the implementation of service.

Answer (score 0):

They are not started automatically unless you explicitly define in the manifest that they should be started at boot time. To do this, you need to add the action

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in your manifest file for your service.

example:

```
 <receiver android:name="MyStartupIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</receiver>
```

Please read this official guide for more detailed information about services:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html